# Keep Datepicker sticked to the textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a Textfield in a Popup. And that textfield contains a Date. Now everything is working fine, when i click in field it opens Datapicker Calender, but when i scroll down , the Datepicker doesnot scroll with the body or textfield, it seperates from textfield.

Like this in Image :

[image]

Any fix for this ?

**Here is my Js Code for Datepicker:**

```
$( "#loadDate" ).datepicker(
{
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: '0' ,
}
);
```

Comment: If you can add a bit of your code. there's some css mismatch

Comment: Not sure if it _can_ be fixed, see old post about the same problem -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859808/jquery-datepicker-does-not-move-with-html-content-when-in-a-scrollable-div

Answer (score 0):

document.documentElement.scrollTop I edit the follwing line on my JS code

```
$.datepicker._pos[1] += input.offsetHeight + document.body.scrollTop;
```

This is because         **document.documentElement.scrollTop**      returns **0**, for me the above code solves my problem

Comment: please have a look in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834857/jquery-ui-datepicker-positioning-problem-when-scrolling-down-webpage)